# Unable to see the whole structure of EDI x12 message in dataweave

Tags: csv, mule, mule-component, dataweave

I am taking a file connector and connecting it to the x12 edi connector, and then passing the x12 837 message to the dataweave. I want to map the batch number (BHT03), Claim number (CLM 01) and  monetary amount (CLM 02) and then create a csv file.

But when I map those and hit the preview in dataweave i am able to see the input payload only till loop 2300. I am unable to see the children or the structure inside of the loop 2300. I tried to map it manually by typing the logic then dragging the elements but i'm getting `null` values.

I saw a video and in it the structure is visible when the guy hits the preview but in my case i am unable to see.

Is there something which I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some stuffs and it worked. We meed to click on the the input left hand side corner in the dataweave and regenerate the sample data then it allows us to select the sample data structure. In this way we can type the values and check the output in preview.